# elastic search add data ECK

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack

I have a local cluster running using minikube. I installed elastic operator with official helm chart and have a elastic cluster running with this yaml:

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: es-qs
spec:
  version: 8.6.2
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 1
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
```

I have never worked with elasticsearch on ECK so my question is: What is the easiest way to manually add datasets to my elastic search cluster for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the simple **Curl** command manually to configure the **Elasticsearch** that will be an easy way.

Ref doc : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

You can use the **postman** also to manage these **curl** or might found a **collection** of necessary **API** online for **ES**.